# Looping through a dataframe and adding values directly into the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv with three columns:

```
df.sample(5)

  company            username     esg_company
320 CIBC             NaN         Canadian Imperial Bank of Commerce
206 Bank of Baroda   NaN         Bank of Baroda
820 Halliburton      halliburton Halliburton Company
112 Luzhou Lao Jiao  NaN         Lu Zhou Lao Jiao Co.Ltd
144 Rabobank         NaN         Rabobank Nederland N.V.
```

Right now I am :

- looping through each company in the company column
- getting the instagram username (chromedriver/selenium)
- appending to a list of usernames
- turning list into column

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  import pandas as pd

  ## defining companies 
  companies = df['company']

  ## creating blank list to house company usernames
  username_list = []

  ## looping though each company
  for company in companies:
      do some stuff here with chromedriver and selenium to get the username from instagram
      ig_handle = username from instagram
      username_list.append(ig_handle)

  df['username'] = username_list
  ```

This list is rather long, and I would like to do it differently since any error means that the list length and the dataframe length aren't the same. I want to:

- loop through the dataframe
- if the username column is blank add ig_handle directly into the dataframe in the proper spot (where the company being searched matches the value in the company column)

I'm not sure if this is possible, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looping over row by row is a very bad idea. Especially, with large data sets. It will take forever and a day to complete.

It is better to use the apply() method to add a new column which process some data via a function/method.

Another thing to note is that you would typically join the data sets with a common id.  This way you can merge() or join() into a single dataframe before modifying.

I created an example by using your sample data and showed both the apply() and join() methods:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 9999)
pd.set_option("display.expand_frame_repr", False)
pd.set_option("display.precision", 5)

## Create test data
data_csv_str = '''id,name,location,description
320,CIBC,null,Canadian Imperial Bank of Commerce
206,Bank of Baroda,null,Bank of Baroda
820,Halliburton,halliburton,Halliburton Company
112,Luzhou Lao Jiao,null,Lu Zhou Lao Jiao Co.Ltd
144,Rabobank,null,Rabobank Nederland N.V.
'''
df_data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_csv_str), sep=',', index_col=0)
print(df_data)
'''
                name     location                         description
id                                                                   
320             CIBC          NaN  Canadian Imperial Bank of Commerce
206   Bank of Baroda          NaN                      Bank of Baroda
820      Halliburton  halliburton                 Halliburton Company
112  Luzhou Lao Jiao          NaN             Lu Zhou Lao Jiao Co.Ltd
144         Rabobank          NaN             Rabobank Nederland N.V.
'''

## Create the instagram user data
data_ig_csv_str = '''id,ig_username
320,bubba
206,carla
555,charles
'''
df_ig_usernames = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_ig_csv_str), sep=',', index_col=0)
print(df_ig_usernames)
'''
    ig_username
id             
320       bubba
206       carla
555     charles
'''

## Join the two dataframes
df_merged = df_data.join(df_ig_usernames)
print(df_merged)
'''
                name     location                         description ig_username
id                                                                               
320             CIBC          NaN  Canadian Imperial Bank of Commerce       bubba
206   Bank of Baroda          NaN                      Bank of Baroda       carla
820      Halliburton  halliburton                 Halliburton Company         NaN
112  Luzhou Lao Jiao          NaN             Lu Zhou Lao Jiao Co.Ltd         NaN
144         Rabobank          NaN             Rabobank Nederland N.V.         NaN
'''

## Create method/function to process and modify data
def myDataProcess(row):
    rowIndex = row.name
    name = row['name']
    abbrev_name = name[0:3]
    ig_name = row['ig_username']
    s = '%s_%s_%s' % (rowIndex, abbrev_name, ig_name)
    return s

## Apply the changes (via method) as new column
df_applied = df_merged
df_applied['id_nameAbbrev_ig'] = df_merged.apply(myDataProcess, axis=1)
print(df_applied)
'''
                name     location                         description ig_username id_nameAbbrev_ig
id                                                                                                
320             CIBC          NaN  Canadian Imperial Bank of Commerce       bubba    320_CIB_bubba
206   Bank of Baroda          NaN                      Bank of Baroda       carla    206_Ban_carla
820      Halliburton  halliburton                 Halliburton Company         NaN      820_Hal_nan
112  Luzhou Lao Jiao          NaN             Lu Zhou Lao Jiao Co.Ltd         NaN      112_Luz_nan
144         Rabobank          NaN             Rabobank Nederland N.V.         NaN      144_Rab_nan
'''
```

Comment: Hi Randy, thank you! I think apply would be a good method although it is unclear to me how your solution gets me there. I am using chromedriver and selenium to get the username of the company - searching for the company on instagram and then recording the verified account if it exists. For example, "halliburton" in the username column is the instagram handle for the company Halliburton.

Comment: @mk2080 are you asking us how to use e.g., selenium? your function, assuming it takes a row as input and returns a scalar as output, should be a drop-in replacement for `myDataProcess`

Comment: In the function/method "myDataProcess", it is just do a silly string concat, but you can process the row however you wish.  But I wouldn't recommend scraping usernames from instagram while using apply() method.  What if the network has a hiccup?  Then you will get all kinds of errors.  Instead, pull the ig names locally first.

Comment: @Randy B, no the selenium is good to go! As of right now, I am looping over a list created from the company column, not the rows...

Comment: @RandyB. I am unsure how to pull the ig names locally first, that is what I thought I was doing with this script. I am trying to scrape the ig names from instagram and store them in the same csv from which I got the list of company names.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  The original question is related to python and pandas.  Now you are talking about selenium.  please clarify.

Comment: If you are trying to use Instagram's api, you will need a developer account:  https://www.instagram.com/developer/  Then you will most likely create some sort of token so you can call their api.  Since Facebook bought Instagram, you may need to create a FB developer account too:  https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/  The APIs are well documented:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/